# Generating multiple Mathematica scripts using batch files

Tags: batch-file

Hopefully this is not a repeated question; I've searched without too many results (mostly not knowing terms to search for).

I currently have a mathematica script, which opens a data file and runs a series of commands on it. In the script, I have to edit certain values for each data file, for example, analysis_20_70.m might read:

```
(* ::Package:: *)

Clear[NN, TxyzAll, q, Txyz, twospace, dps, threespace, threeclosed, plane]
datChoice = ReadList[
    "/n/homeserver2/user2a/scallion/mathematica/20_70.dat", {Number, Number, Number}]; 
NN = 51; 
% LOTS OF CODE HERE
Export[
   "/n/homeserver2/user2a/scallion/mathematica/20_70_time.txt", 
   time]; 
Exit[]
```

As such, editing it for every file I want to run is inefficient. I'm new to scripting in general, but thought that I could use batch scripting to automate this process (i.e. script 1 reads 20_70.dat, NN = 51, script 2 reads 20_75.dat, NN = 56, script 3 reads 20_80.dat, NN = 61, etc.)

So far, I've cobbled together something like this:

```
@echo off
set "begin=20"
set "end=150"
set "count=70"

:LOOP
if %count% GTR %end% (goto END)

(
echo (* ::Package:: *)
echo Clear[NN, TxyzAll, q, Txyz, twospace, dps, threespace, threeclosed, plane]
echo datChoice = ReadList[
echo     "/n/homeserver2/user2a/scallion/mathematica/20_70.dat", {Number, Number, Number}]; 
echo NN = 51; 
echo Exit[]
) > testfile_%begin%.txt

set /a count+=5
goto LOOP
:END
```

(ideally 20_70.dat would become something like %begin%_%count%.dat).

if I replace the middle with something simple, like echo hello world > testfile_%begin%.txt, I have no problems. However, trying to print the entire mathematica script seems messy, and I don't know if there will be newline problems/hidden characters in the resulting file. Thus, my questions:

1). is there a better way to print multiple lines than to put echo in front of each line? and if so, would I retain the ability to change the filenames with the counters?

2). my code, naturally, has ( ) [ ] ; = and other reserved characters everywhere, so it seemed I have to either put each line in quotations (in which case I can't remove the quotes), or manually escape every single violation. I can go through and do it, but would like to know if there is a better way.

3). it may be that batch files are not the way to go. If there are other ways to tackle this problem, I'm up for trying anything.

Thanks all for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

1) The command [`echo`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) prints a text from the script content to a file (including `stdout`, of course). I recommend also using of [`type`](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) which can copy text from another file and in this case, you don't have to take care of special characters. So I would write something like this:

```
type static_begin.txt > output.txt
echo A %dynamic% part >> output.txt
type static_end.txt >> output.txt
```

It just copies the static (unvarying) begin and end and allows to put something varying between them. The operator `>>` means appending to the file end.

2) You can [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) special characters of batch-files using `^`, for example `^(`.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
SET "skeleton=%~1"
SET /a count=0
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%S IN ("%~2") DO (
 CALL :genscript %%S
)

GOTO :EOF
:genscript
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET /a paramcount=1
:paramloop
SET "$%paramcount%=%1"
IF DEFINED $%paramcount% SET /a paramcount+=1&shift&GOTO paramloop
SET /a paramcount -=1

:: Now have $1=1st param, $2=second, etc.

:: Simple substitution : only 2 parameters (dat and NN)
IF DEFINED $3 GOTO loopy

CALL :genfile %$1% %$2%
GOTO :eof

:: We have more than two parameters in the data line.
:: Let's define params as %1=start, %2=incr, %3=end for first item
:: %4=start, %5=incr, %6=end for second item
:: %7=start, %8=incr, %9=end for third item
:: how it's done - up to the user
:loopy

FOR /L %%a IN (%$1% %$2% %$3%) DO (
 FOR /L %%b IN (%$4% %$5% %$6%) DO (
  FOR /L %%c IN (%$7% %$8% %$9%) DO (
   CALL :genfile %%a_%%b %%c
  )
 )
)

GOTO :eof

:genfile
SET "$batchline1=    "/n/homeserver2/user2a/scallion/mathematica/%1.dat", {Number, Number, Number}];"
SET "$batchline2=NN = %2;"
SET "$batchline3=   "/n/homeserver2/user2a/scallion/mathematica/%1_time.txt","
SET /a count+=1
SET outscript=script%count%.m
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%L IN ('FINDSTR /n /r "$" "%skeleton%"') DO (
  SET "line=%%M"
  CALL :subs
  IF DEFINED line ECHO(%%M
 )
)>"%destdir%\%outscript%"
GOTO :eof

:: Do the substitution
:subs
:: if LINE is not defined, empty line
IF NOT DEFINED line SET line=Y&GOTO :EOF
SET "line=%line:"=%"
SET "line=%line:&=%"
SET "line=%line:)=%"
SET "line=%line:(=%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%s IN ('set $batch') DO IF "%%s"=="$%line%" (
 SET "line="
 ECHO(%%t
 GOTO :eof
)
GOTO :eof
```

I believe this will work.

Run it as `thisbatch skeleton.txt controlfile.txt`

Where skeleton.txt is

```
(* ::Package:: *)

Clear[NN, TxyzAll, q, Txyz, twospace, dps, threespace, threeclosed, plane]
datChoice = ReadList[
batchline1
batchline2
% LOTS OF CODE HERE
Export[
batchline3
   time]; 
Exit[]
```

That is, your original .m file, with the variable lines replaced by `batchline1..3` and those lines are built and substituted by the script.

controlfile.txt is

```
20_70 51
20 1 22 70 2 74 51 5 66
```

which will build the script from the skeleton, substituting `20_70` and `51` strategically, then, just because it's possible (without knowing your situation in any way) similarly build scripts for all combinations of `(20 to 22 step 1)_(70 to 74 step 2)` and `(51 to 66 step 5)`

Seemed to work for me...